# Is it possible to return Dynamic Columns using Table Valued Function in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, function, user-defined-functions

I have written some set of statements which returns a table with some columns. But we dont know exactly which column it returns.
In table valued function, I dont know how to return the Dynamic columns of the table.
How to write the table value function for this scenario? If this is not possible then what would be the alternative for this task?
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table-valued function requires static columns (names and types). If you want dynamic columns in result-set, use procedure instead of function.

Comment: But If it is a table valued function means, i can easily write a view using that function. But If i use Stored Procedure then how can I call using the View? Is there any solutions for this?

Comment: Stored procedure can not be used in view/table-valued-function :(. However stored procedures can be used from SQL batches or applications (c#/vb.net/php/deplhi/c/c++/etc...) similary like views of table-valued-functions.